# How to map the alphabets to a list?

Tags: python-3.x, list

```
list(map(chr,range(97,123)))
```

please explain the above code.I do not get why it is written (97,123)

Comment: Break it down to the basics. Do you understand `range`? Do you understand `chr`? Do you understand `map`? Do you understand `list`?

Comment: Also, FWIW, the same output can be achieved with `import string ; list(string.ascii_lowercase)`

Comment: Yes I do understand list,range,map,list  but i did not know chr.But I got my answer.thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Hello

list() is normaly used for converting.
Therefore your above example simply converts a map object of chars to a list.

```
help(chr)
alphab=list(map(chr,range(65,91)))
alphab=alphab+list(map(chr,range(97,123)))
for char in alphab:
 print(char)
```

PS: I learned the Capitals first.